# Function that tabulates for specific values and returns counts

Tags: r

Imagine you have a vector `x`:

```
x <- c("C", "A", "B", "B", "A", "D", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "D", "C", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "D", "A", "D", "A", "D", "A", "A", "D", "D", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "C", "B")
```

You can make a table using:

```
table(x)
# x
#  A  B  C  D 
# 22 14  7  7
```

What if you only want the table to include certain values (eg. 'A' and 'B'), or you want the table to include values that might not exist in `x`?

This is my attempt:

```
tab_specific_values <- function(vector, values) `names<-`(rowSums(outer(values, vector, `==`)), values)
```

For example:

```
tab_specific_values(vector = x, values = c('A', 'B'))
# A  B 
# 22 14
```

Or if we specify a value that does not exist in `x`

```
tab_specific_values(vector = x, values = c('A', 'B', 'E'))
# A  B  E 
# 22 14  0
```

Is there an existing dedicated function that does this, or do you have a better approach? I suspect my function `tab_specific_values` might not be the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to *factor* with certain levels, then *table*:

```
#my values
v <- c("A", "B", "E")

table(factor(x, levels = v))
#  A  B  E 
# 22 14  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Benchmarking:

```
microbenchmark(
  a = table(x, exclude = c('A', 'B')),
  b = table(factor(x, levels = c('C', 'D'))),
  c = tab_specific_values(vector = x, values = c('C', 'D')),
  times = 1000
)

Unit: microseconds
 expr     min       lq      mean  median       uq       max neval
    a 116.401 131.6505 177.20030 145.201 236.8010   604.701  1000
    b  49.302  60.0010  92.33422  66.501 109.4510 10974.101  1000
    c  13.301  20.1005  29.09018  24.201  36.3015   134.901  1000
```

When x is 1,000,000 long:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
    a 119.3651 131.24110 142.63383 137.50385 144.07945 233.1265   100
    b  43.9441  48.18640  58.24316  54.75485  59.12390 129.5087   100
    c  48.9598  55.33825  67.03932  62.64145  65.93755 152.9490   100
```